# "were studied" or " was Studied"

Tags: grammar

"The availability of agricultural residues and animal fat in China **were** studied".

In above sentences I have a little doubt that it should be **Were** or **Was**
in the same way, can be **IS** studied or **are** studied?
which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's singular - 'was' or 'is' - because it's the **availability** that was/is studied, not the residues & fats.